# How can I access LoginComponent in User module with my-app/login route (NOT my-app/user/login)?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the route my-app/user point to ListUserComponent of User module. How can I access LoginComponent in User module with my-app/login route (NOT my-app/user/login)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a redirect.  In your root module routing paths (`AppRoutingModule`), set:

```
routes = [
   {path:'my-app/login', redirectTo:'/my-app/user/login'}
]
```

And in the feature module routing paths (`UserRoutingModule`), set:

```
routes = [
   {path:'my-app/user/login', component:LoginComponent}
]
```

This should accomplish your goal:

> How can I access LoginComponent in User module with my-app/login route

If your app features don't line up with natural routes (eg: the `LoginComponent` belongs to `UserModule` but you don't want the login path to enter user module), you may have a bigger issue. Rethink your module architecture. Perhaps Login should be part of the root module.

Comment: That's awesome, but is there any way that the URL still stay on `/my-app/login`. Do I need to move the login component to the root module? thanks

Comment: That's what I would do. The path and the component location should be in sync. All components of the same module should have paths that begin the same way.